# Were there other people in the same position as Neo with different choices at the end of “The Matrix Reloaded"?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-matrix-reloaded

In the climactic scene of *The Matrix Reloaded*, the protagonist, Neo, faces a critical decision involving two doors, each representing a different path and potential outcome in the ongoing conflict between humans and machines.

Were there instances of other characters within the Matrix universe confronted with similar pivotal choices, where they had to decide between two distinct paths, each leading to vastly different consequences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Architect, assuming we can trust him to have told the truth, explicitly [states](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cHZl2naX1Xk) that Neo is not the first 'The One', and that others were forced to make the same choice as our Neo.

> *The Matrix is older than you know. I prefer counting from the emergence of one integral anomaly to the emergence of the next, in which case this is the sixth version.*
>
> ...
>
> *Your five predecessors were by design based on a similar predication*

And that the prior iterations made the 'correct' choice.

> *The door to your right leads to the source, and the salvation of Zion. The door to the left leads back to the matrix, to her, and to the end
> of your species. As you adequately put, the problem is choice. But we
> already know what you're going to do, don't we?*

Neo, on the other hand is led by <s>the dumbstick</s> his love of Trinity into making the decision to continue the fight against the Machine Armies.

---

Note that the others Neos pictured on the walls behind him aren't earlier versions of Neo, they appear to be *predictions* of what the current Neo might say and do as the conversation progresses.

Comment: "they appear to be predictions" — citation needed. Imo, showing previous versions of the One in the same situation would be beneficial "to help" the Current One with the choice. Presenting the ability to predict future, would make the Current One think he has no choice, as if the Architect already knows how it would be. But they need Neo to make a choice, not follow the prediction of the future. Because "nearly 99% of all test subjects accepted the program, as long as they were given a choice, even if they were only aware of the choice at a near unconscious level.".

Comment: Also, the other Neos on the screen behind the Current One are saying [`“Five versions? Three? I’ve been lied too. This is bullshit.`](https://youtu.be/cHZl2naX1Xk?t=134). It would be quite weird for the Architect to predict that Neo will talk about "Fifth" or "Third" versions right after he was told he is in the Sixth version. What are they predicting? That Neo may not have short term memory?

Comment: @user28434 - The script is reasonably clear that these are versions of our Neo: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/76959/20774

Comment: how would you explain "ARCHITECT
Quite right. Interesting. That was
quicker than the others.
*Now the Neos respond differently*" from the script then? In the video it's https://youtu.be/cHZl2naX1Xk?t=118

Comment: @user28434 - Because he's had a similar conversation with other 'The Ones' in the past. That doesn't mean that the video is showing those conversations.

Comment: but why would it's emphasized that Neos on the screens start responding differently at **exact** moment the Architect mentions the others?

Comment: @user28434 - The Architect is predicting Neo's responses. Some he gets right, some he gets wrong.

Comment: it doesn't make sense to show failed attempts to predict to someone you're trying to convince you can predict every action.

Comment: @user28434 - That's not the purpose of this conversation. Neo has already made his choice, now the Architect needs to explain to him what the consquences will be

Comment: @user28434 But why are there so many TVs? If there are five previous versions, there should be five different TVs. And they should have one to four TVs behind them. Also, I don't the previous ones were different versions of Neo. They were distinct human beings that simply shared the same role. They didn't look like Keanu Reeves.

Comment: @Acccumulation - The TVs appear to show what the Architect is thinking or paying attention to. He can pay attention to lots of things at once

Comment: @Acccumulation, those TVs were used to show different stuff not just Neo. Also, humans are **grown** in Matrix, without any contact between their parents, they are artificially made. Reusing the same genome would make solving the problem of unpredictability easier — one less variable to worry about. Therefore it would be logical to make **all** of them clones of Keanu Reeves.

Comment: @Valorum But the point is that if there are only five past Ones, then the Architect has only five other things to be thinking about.

Comment: *they appear to be predictions* - that's how AI works. Same as your brain. The Architect has *everything* from two separate worlds to think about, one of which he's thought about at least six times, with *any* number of iterations thereof, with as much computing power was available. - Instead of the best episode of POI where it starts the show over x10 with iteration #6M being the one to go with (or i.e., Dr. Strange), he's doing it all at once, and bragging about it with a million dollar CRT display setup for our benefit.